# Lock wait time out exceed restart transaction

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction

I had got error on the lock wait time out so below I got 3 samples taken. One I took before the increase innodb_lock_wait_timeout to 120. So is there anything else I must tweak based on the logs below.

Before increasing

```
1280
MySQL thread id 183, query id 465855 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491326, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388595255040
MySQL thread id 185, query id 479140 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491044, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388594988800
MySQL thread id 186, query id 463354 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491324, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388599514880
MySQL thread id 147, query id 479132 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491100, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388724803328
MySQL thread id 133, query id 477373 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491278, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388596586240
MySQL thread id 168, query id 476621 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2490727, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388596852480
MySQL thread id 167, query id 463538 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491140, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388597651200
MySQL thread id 163, query id 463529 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491312, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388598183680
MySQL thread id 157, query id 479053 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491294, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388599781120
MySQL thread id 146, query id 478179 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491225, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388600579840
MySQL thread id 143, query id 465144 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491305, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388601112320
MySQL thread id 141, query id 478993 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491290, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388601378560
MySQL thread id 139, query id 477383 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2490874, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388724270848
MySQL thread id 135, query id 463385 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491277, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388601911040
MySQL thread id 137, query id 479062 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491135, not started, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388725069568
MySQL thread id 131, query id 463384 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2491310, ACTIVE 29 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388597384960 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 165, query id 479034 192.168.100.11 vscs1 Updating
Update tblID Set lastValue=4372  Where tableName='tblUnAst'
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2491311, sees < 0 2490366
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 29 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 19 page no 3 n bits 72 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `scs`.`tblID` trx id 0 2491310 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2
------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 2491307, ACTIVE 38 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388597917440 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 162, query id 479004 192.168.100.11 vscs1 Updating
Update tblID Set lastValue=4372  Where tableName='tblUnAst'
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2491308, sees < 0 2490366
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 38 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 19 page no 3 n bits 72 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `scs`.`tblID` trx id 0 2491307 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2
------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 2491299, ACTIVE 46 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388388042496 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 132, query id 478208 192.168.100.11 vscs1 Updating
Update tblID Set lastValue=4372  Where tableName='tblUnAst'
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2491300, sees < 0 2490366
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 46 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 19 page no 3 n bits 72 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `scs`.`tblID` trx id 0 2491299 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2
------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 2491281, ACTIVE 64 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388724004608
1 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 136, query id 477325 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2491282, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2491256, ACTIVE 108 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388598449920
1 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 158, query id 467973 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2491257, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2491199, ACTIVE 153 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388600846080
1 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 142, query id 464318 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2491200, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2491086, ACTIVE 265 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388724537088
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 134, query id 453252 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2491087, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490842, ACTIVE 587 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388600313600
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 144, query id 404624 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490843, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490708, ACTIVE 716 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388593923840
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 5
MySQL thread id 199, query id 370321 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490709, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490648, ACTIVE 744 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388601644800
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 138, query id 369508 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490649, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490642, ACTIVE 750 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388594190080
1 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 192, query id 367922 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490643, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490555, ACTIVE 840 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388595787520
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 4
MySQL thread id 182, query id 349533 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490556, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490533, ACTIVE 852 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388596053760
1 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 177, query id 345850 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490534, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490381, ACTIVE 987 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388600047360
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 145, query id 84142 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490382, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490376, ACTIVE 993 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388598716160
1 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 150, query id 67292 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490377, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490371, ACTIVE 995 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388598982400
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 5
MySQL thread id 149, query id 58852 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490372, sees < 0 2490366
---TRANSACTION 0 2490366, ACTIVE 998 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388599248640
1 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 148, query id 50401 192.168.100.11 vscs1
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 2490367, sees < 0 2490367
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0, aio writes: 0,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
23934 OS file reads, 2622 OS file writes, 1521 OS fsyncs
4.00 reads/s, 19894 avg bytes/read, 1.14 writes/s, 1.14 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2,
641 inserts, 641 merged recs, 513 merges
Hash table size 17393, node heap has 7 buffer(s)
110.27 hash searches/s, 64.42 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 0 1454407131
Log flushed up to   0 1454407131
Last checkpoint at  0 1454403687
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
856 log i/o's done, 1.14 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 21296456; in additional pool allocated 1048576
Dictionary memory allocated 390168
Buffer pool size   512
Free buffers       0
Database pages     505
Modified db pages  15
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages read 128135, created 12, written 1874
4.86 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 992 / 1000
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
18 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 6622, id 140388612400896, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 332, updated 353, deleted 0, read 10910686
0.29 inserts/s, 0.43 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 473.93 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
No query specified
```

1st sample after increase

```
show engine innodb status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name:
Status:
=====================================
130507  5:13:33 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 51 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 20519, signal count 20505
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 4183, OS waits 15
RW-shared spins 45944, OS waits 20490; RW-excl spins 19, OS waits 12
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 2493509
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 2493504 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 37
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 2493455, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471080023808
MySQL thread id 90, query id 114373 192.168.100.11 websvs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493402, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471202846464
MySQL thread id 25, query id 105647 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493389, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471203112704
MySQL thread id 24, query id 105583 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493100, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471203645184
MySQL thread id 22, query id 92664 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493277, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471210927872
MySQL thread id 8, query id 103502 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492963, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471080556288
MySQL thread id 38, query id 91212 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471080290048
MySQL thread id 43, query id 114612 localhost root
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 0 2493507, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471200716544
MySQL thread id 34, query id 114611 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493506, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471200982784
MySQL thread id 33, query id 114601 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492547, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471201781504
MySQL thread id 30, query id 76507 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493058, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471202047744
MySQL thread id 29, query id 91747 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493421, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471211992832
MySQL thread id 4, query id 114177 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493484, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471202313984
MySQL thread id 27, query id 114564 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493411, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471202580224
MySQL thread id 26, query id 105708 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493292, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471203378944
MySQL thread id 23, query id 105067 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493166, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471203911424
MySQL thread id 21, query id 101445 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492826, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471204177664
MySQL thread id 20, query id 90551 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492515, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471204443904
MySQL thread id 19, query id 76331 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492452, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140470193747712
MySQL thread id 18, query id 71237 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492272, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471204710144
MySQL thread id 15, query id 91426 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492269, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471204976384
MySQL thread id 14, query id 92982 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492304, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471205508864
MySQL thread id 12, query id 105224 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492687, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471210129152
MySQL thread id 11, query id 81763 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492665, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471210395392
MySQL thread id 10, query id 80152 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492476, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471210661632
MySQL thread id 9, query id 73007 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2493048, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471211194112
MySQL thread id 7, query id 91693 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492481, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471211460352
MySQL thread id 6, query id 73035 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2492600, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471211726592
MySQL thread id 5, query id 77571 192.168.100.11 vscs1
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0, aio writes: 0,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
11811 OS file reads, 2692 OS file writes, 1778 OS fsyncs
4.80 reads/s, 117496 avg bytes/read, 3.47 writes/s, 2.14 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2,
713 inserts, 713 merged recs, 288 merges
Hash table size 17393, node heap has 4 buffer(s)
140.62 hash searches/s, 73.39 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 0 1455084521
Log flushed up to   0 1455084521
Last checkpoint at  0 1455083429
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
1301 log i/o's done, 1.57 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 21501264; in additional pool allocated 1048576
Dictionary memory allocated 390168
Buffer pool size   512
Free buffers       0
Database pages     508
Modified db pages  4
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages read 55114, created 19, written 1524
34.45 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 1.90 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 976 / 1000
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 7268, id 140471091312384, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 350, updated 616, deleted 0, read 4394330
0.22 inserts/s, 0.69 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 6064.16 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

2nd sample after increase

```
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name:
Status:
=====================================
130507 12:26:51 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 11 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 474709, signal count 474267
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 83167, OS waits 190
RW-shared spins 1055681, OS waits 474391; RW-excl spins 171, OS waits 84
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 2507435
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 2507433 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 24
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471205242624
MySQL thread id 2342, query id 2258106 localhost root
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 0 2507431, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471201515264
MySQL thread id 31, query id 2249681 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507286, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471080822528
MySQL thread id 37, query id 2237933 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2506767, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471201249024
MySQL thread id 32, query id 2068631 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507181, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471202846464
MySQL thread id 25, query id 2217691 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507426, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471203112704
MySQL thread id 24, query id 2249653 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507057, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471203645184
MySQL thread id 22, query id 2241042 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507239, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471210927872
MySQL thread id 8, query id 2248183 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507073, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471080556288
MySQL thread id 38, query id 2195237 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2506947, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471200716544
MySQL thread id 34, query id 2110790 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507401, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471200982784
MySQL thread id 33, query id 2247238 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507364, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471201781504
MySQL thread id 30, query id 2244145 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507147, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471202047744
MySQL thread id 29, query id 2237934 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2506850, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471211992832
MySQL thread id 4, query id 2081660 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507429, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471202313984
MySQL thread id 27, query id 2249669 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507433, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471202580224
MySQL thread id 26, query id 2258105 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507376, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471203378944
MySQL thread id 23, query id 2244897 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507264, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471203911424
MySQL thread id 21, query id 2228700 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507407, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471204177664
MySQL thread id 20, query id 2247950 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507418, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471204443904
MySQL thread id 19, query id 2249083 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2506774, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140470193747712
MySQL thread id 18, query id 2228732 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507290, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471204710144
MySQL thread id 15, query id 2237960 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507224, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471204976384
MySQL thread id 14, query id 2244173 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2506999, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471205508864
MySQL thread id 12, query id 2131568 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507275, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471210129152
MySQL thread id 11, query id 2237180 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507414, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471210395392
MySQL thread id 10, query id 2248290 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2506827, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471210661632
MySQL thread id 9, query id 2071734 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507368, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471211194112
MySQL thread id 7, query id 2244168 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507279, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471211460352
MySQL thread id 6, query id 2249682 192.168.100.11 vscs1
---TRANSACTION 0 2507300, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471211726592
MySQL thread id 5, query id 2241023 192.168.100.11 vscs1
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0, aio writes: 0,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
251091 OS file reads, 45023 OS file writes, 25818 OS fsyncs
3.64 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 0.36 writes/s, 0.36 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2,
9852 inserts, 9852 merged recs, 8373 merges
Hash table size 17393, node heap has 4 buffer(s)
5.36 hash searches/s, 23.27 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 0 1460632209
Log flushed up to   0 1460632209
Last checkpoint at  0 1460630034
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
15288 log i/o's done, 0.36 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 21342016; in additional pool allocated 1045248
Dictionary memory allocated 390168
Buffer pool size   512
Free buffers       0
Database pages     508
Modified db pages  22
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages read 1554136, created 189, written 31373
3.64 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 977 / 1000
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 7268, id 140471091312384, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 4574, updated 5967, deleted 0, read 154891781
0.18 inserts/s, 0.18 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 250.16 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

select version();

```
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.1.69-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

show global variables like 'innodb%';

```
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                  |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index              | ON                     |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size         | 1048576                |
| innodb_autoextend_increment             | 8                      |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                 | 8388608                |
| innodb_checksums                        | ON                     |
| innodb_commit_concurrency               | 0                      |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets              | 500                    |
| innodb_data_file_path                   | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                    |                        |
| innodb_doublewrite                      | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                    | 1                      |
| innodb_file_io_threads                  | 4                      |
| innodb_file_per_table                   | ON                     |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit          | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                     |                        |
| innodb_force_recovery                   | 0                      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                | 120                    |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_log_file_size                    | 5242880                |
| innodb_log_files_in_group               | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir               | ./                     |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct              | 90                     |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                    | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups              | 1                      |
| innodb_open_files                       | 300                    |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout              | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_method                     | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                | ON                     |
| innodb_support_xa                       | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                  | 20                     |
| innodb_table_locks                      | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency               | 8                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay               | 10000                  |
| innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm | ON                     |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
36 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please run these queries and post them in the question: 1) `SELECT VERSION();` 2) `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I have updated my question with both the results above.

Comment: @Rolando do I need to provide anything else please?

Answer (score 1):

Please look carefully at the queries that are locking

The `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` is incomplete

I cannot fully tell you anything more because you gave me three transactions that

- execute the exact same query
- lock the same page in the `GEN_CLUST_INDEX`

as shown from your display

```
---TRANSACTION 0 2491310, ACTIVE 29 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388597384960 starting index read
Update tblID Set lastValue=4372  Where tableName='tblUnAst'

---TRANSACTION 0 2491307, ACTIVE 38 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388597917440 starting index read
Update tblID Set lastValue=4372  Where tableName='tblUnAst'

---TRANSACTION 0 2491299, ACTIVE 46 sec, process no 6622, OS thread id 140388388042496 starting index read
Update tblID Set lastValue=4372  Where tableName='tblUnAst'
```

Notwithstanding, there are undo log entries coming from several transactions.

This situation is so reminiscent of three question from one person ([**RedBlueThing**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2043/redbluething)) that I helped troubleshoot. Here were those posts:

- `Jun 14, 2011` : [Reasons for occasionally slow queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/reasons-for-occasionally-slow-queries/3305#3305)
- `Jun 08, 2011` : [Will these two queries result in a deadlock if executed in sequence?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence/3224#3224)
- `Jun 06, 2011` : [Trouble deciphering a deadlock in an innodb status log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/trouble-deciphering-a-deadlock-in-an-innodb-status-log/3185#3185)

[**RedBlueThing**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2043/redbluething) solved it by changing his code, not his configuration.

In light of this, look back at the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` output. From what you provided, I see many transactions and many undo log entries from multiple transactions. Apparently, this came from multiple transactions trying to run the exact same query.

## RECOMMENDATION

You are using a very old version of the InnoDB Storage Engine. You should upgrade to the latest MySQL as you can set a higher number of read and write I/O threads The new InnoDB can also access up to 48 cores. If you do not upgrade, the very least you should do is set innodb_thread_concurrency to 0.

As @altmannmarcelo mentioned in the comment below, you can install the InnoDB Plugin. See my post [MySQL - Installing InnoDB Plugin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18203/mysql-installing-innodb-plugin/18240#18240)

Comment: if update is not an option, you should at least install innodb plugin (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-plugin-installation.html)

Comment: @altmannmarcelo you are right. Since MySQL 5.1.69 is used (which is greater than MySQL 5.1.38, when the plugin first became available), The InnoDB plugin should be somewhere in the plugin_dir. It just needs installation : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18240/877

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA how will innodb_thread_concurrency help me here? I will read up on the plugin as when you update centos machine it always keep some older version software where it claim to be stable. This is what I got from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G is there any other command to retrieve further details? How do you see "the many transactions and many undo log entries from multiple transactions. Apparently, this came from multiple transactions trying to run the exact same query" How do you see these I would like to learn more on this ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA basically these db is accessed via php codes and java. The java codes is the one with one transaction and many queries in it. I am not too sure which queries could be the culprit any method to highlight on this?

Comment: All those transactions (running and waiting (started and not running)) should have their SQL statement visible in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`.

Comment: As for `innodb_thread_concurrency`, don't worry. The default is 0 for MySQL 5.5, so no need to insert it into my.cnf.

Comment: For e.g. I have these many TRANSACTION 0 2507431, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471201515264 means it is waiting is it? What it might be waiting then?

Comment: Is it default in my version my mysql 5.1.69?

Comment: Oh you have MySQL 5.1 ? Then you need to set innodb_thread_concurrency to 0 right away. Setting this to a nonzero value tends to inhibit InnoDB from maxing out its performance. See my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13870/877 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core/5670#5670. Even with this, I would recommend you upgrade to MySQL 5.5/5.6.

Comment: I plan too must is discourage by centos as it claims to install the most stable version of the software I am now in a limbo to upgrade or not?

Comment: I want to ask you what does this mean TRANSACTION 0 2507431, not started, process no 7268, OS thread id 140471201515264