# Should the Redo log on a production MySQL server be configured to another location?

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction-log

Concerning the innoDB storage engine, should the `innodb_log_group_home_dir` option (The directory path to the InnoDB log files) be configured to another disk, other than the default directory, in order to separate the log I/O activity from the actual data files?

Are there advantages, like in other DBMS, to put the data directory on a RAID5 storage volume and the redo log on a RAID1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be a good idea. I have mentioned a [FaceBook Engineer's Blog about doing that](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2009/05/tables-on-ssd-redobinlogsystem.html), along with putting the DoubleWrite Buffer and Tablespace Files in other places, in my other posts

- `Feb 24, 2012` : [Tuning dedicated Percona Server with XtraDB for OLTP](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/tuning-dedicated-percona-server-with-xtradb-for-oltp/13870#13870) (Also See Switching Gears TO RAID)
- `Feb 06, 2014` : [MySQL on SSD - what are the disadvantages?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58341/mysql-on-ssd-what-are-the-disadvantages/58375#58375)
- `Jan 27, 2015` : [what would be the primary disadvantages of splitting my tables into table spaces and/or separate schemata](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90092/what-would-be-the-primary-disadvantages-of-splitting-my-tables-into-table-spaces/90262#90262)

## RAID5 ??? OMG, NO !!!!!

Please do not put anything InnoDB-related in RAID5

- `Feb 14, 2012` : [Is raid 5 suitable for a mysql installation?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12977/is-raid-5-suitable-for-a-mysql-installation/13036#13036)
- `Mar 24, 2013` : [Innodb table is taking randomly long time to execute the insert query and in show processlist showing as queryend/updating](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42989/innodb-table-is-taking-randomly-long-time-to-execute-the-insert-query-and-in-sho/43021#43021)

Since you will need the the redo logs only in the event of crash recovery, I would go with RAID10 SAS Drives for the redo logs because they are sequentially written files. I would shy away from RAID1 because you want full redundancy of disk in the event of a disk crash. RAID5 does plenty of parity checking which can inhibit sequential writes.

Answer (score 0):

RAID-5 controller with a battery-backed write cache is excellent.  Writes appear (to MySQL) to be instantaneous.

When comparing RAID-5 to -10, you need to decide whether you are comparing N drives to N drives or comparing M GB to M GB.

N drives:  RAID-10 scatters its reads across N drives; So does RAID-5.  Writes hit 2 drives in either case, but the read-modify-write for the parity block may make RAID-5 slightly slower.

M GB:  Now you are comparing, say, 6 RAID-10 drives to 4 RAID-5 drives (to get 3 drives' worth of space).  So RAID-10 probably wins on both reads and writes.

But...  Unless you are saturating the I/O, the RAID controller hides the differences.

RAID-5 or -10 is better than manually putting files on different drives:

- Less risk of running out of disk space on one drive when there is plenty of free space on other drives.
- The I/O is more evenly spread out, hence better throughput.  By manually splitting, you are likely to get one drive over-worked while the others are less busy.

One problem with "battery-backed":  The controller periodically drains the battery to extend its lifetime.  At that point, the write cache is turned off, and writes become miserably slow.  (This cycling lasts a few minutes, and happens maybe twice a year.)

Both RAID-5 and RAID-10 can withstand a single-drive failure.  -5 cannot handle 2 failures at once; -10 can handle *some* 2-drive failures.  (See also -6.)

Since drive failure is one of *many* things that can go bad (motherboard, controller, power surge, earthquake, tornado, manual goof, software bug, overtemp due to AC failure, ...), I think it is shortsighted to think only about RAID (or even DRBD) when looking at HA, BCP, etc.

I vote for a *single filesystem* with N drives and RAID-5 or -10 with BBWC.

Well, that's for spinning drives.

For a mixed HD/SSD system, put "logs" on HD since sequential access is relatively fast; put InnoDB stuff on SSD, where random access is important.  If possible, get a brand of SSD that guarantees atomic 16KB writes, then turn off InnoDB's "double write buffering".

For all-SSD, make sure the wear-leveling is good enough so that all drives don't wear out at the same time (thereby rendering RAID useless).