# MySQL Create Table with Partition Very Slow on server machine

Tags: mysql, windows-server

Following create table statement with Partition

runs in 10 Second on My Development Machine windows 7, i5 , 8GBRam, single disk

runs in 16 Second on Virtual Machine windows server 2012 , xeon 2GHz , 615MB Ram, single disk

While takes 100 Seconds on my server machine Windows server 2008 R2 Standard, xeon 2.4 2 Processors, 32 GB Ram, ATA SCSI Mirror drives

I am not able to understand why there is so much performance difference ..

Related  question on MySql forum http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,392502,392502

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestSpeed`.`CTM` (
  `ServerID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `ClientID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `CommunityID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`,`CommunityID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `IX_CTM` (`ServerID` ASC,`CommunityID`),
  INDEX `IX_CTM_ClientID` (`ClientID` ASC))
PARTITION BY HASH (CommunityID) PARTITIONS 300;
```

**Variables**

```
> Variable_name Value auto_increment_increment  1 auto_increment_offset 1
> autocommit    ON automatic_sp_privileges  ON back_log 80
> basedir   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\ big_tables OFF
> bind_address  * binlog_cache_size 32768 binlog_checksum   CRC32
> binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates   OFF
> binlog_error_action   IGNORE_ERROR binlog_format  STATEMENT
> binlog_gtid_simple_recovery   OFF binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
> binlog_order_commits  ON binlog_row_image FULL
> binlog_rows_query_log_events  OFF binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
> binlogging_impossible_mode    IGNORE_ERROR
> block_encryption_mode aes-128-ecb bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
> character_set_client  utf8 character_set_connection   utf8
> character_set_database    utf8 character_set_filesystem   binary
> character_set_results utf8 character_set_server   utf8
> character_set_system  utf8 character_sets_dir C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\
> collation_connection  utf8_general_ci
> collation_database    utf8_general_ci collation_server    utf8_general_ci
> completion_type   NO_CHAIN concurrent_insert  AUTO connect_timeout    10
> core_file OFF datadir C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Data\
> date_format   %Y-%m-%d datetime_format    %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
> default_storage_engine    InnoDB default_tmp_storage_engine   InnoDB
> default_week_format   0 delay_key_write   ON delayed_insert_limit 100
> delayed_insert_timeout    300 delayed_queue_size  1000
> disconnect_on_expired_password    ON div_precision_increment  4
> end_markers_in_json   OFF enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
> eq_range_index_dive_limit 10 event_scheduler  OFF expire_logs_days    0
> explicit_defaults_for_timestamp   OFF flush   OFF flush_time  0
> foreign_key_checks    ON ft_boolean_syntax    + -><()~*:""&|
> ft_max_word_len   84 ft_min_word_len  4 ft_query_expansion_limit  20
> ft_stopword_file  (built-in) general_log  OFF
> general_log_file  CL-T226-164CN.log group_concat_max_len  1024
> gtid_executed  gtid_mode  OFF gtid_owned   gtid_purged    
> have_compress YES have_crypt  NO have_dynamic_loading YES
> have_geometry YES have_openssl    DISABLED have_profiling YES
> have_query_cache  YES have_rtree_keys YES have_ssl    DISABLED
> have_symlink  YES host_cache_size 279 hostname    cl-t226-164cn
> ignore_builtin_innodb OFF ignore_db_dirs   init_connect    init_file  
> init_slave     innodb_adaptive_flushing   ON
> innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm  10 innodb_adaptive_hash_index   ON
> innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay   150000
> innodb_additional_mem_pool_size   33554432
> innodb_api_bk_commit_interval 5 innodb_api_disable_rowlock    OFF
> innodb_api_enable_binlog  OFF innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
> innodb_api_trx_level  0 innodb_autoextend_increment   64
> innodb_autoinc_lock_mode  1 innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown   OFF
> innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now   OFF
> innodb_buffer_pool_filename   ib_buffer_pool
> innodb_buffer_pool_instances  8 innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort OFF
> innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup    OFF innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
> innodb_buffer_pool_size   10737418240 innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
> innodb_change_buffering   all innodb_checksum_algorithm   crc32
> innodb_checksums  ON innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled OFF
> innodb_commit_concurrency 0 innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct  5
> innodb_compression_level  6 innodb_compression_pad_pct_max    50
> innodb_concurrency_tickets    5000
> innodb_data_file_path ibdata1:12M:autoextend innodb_data_home_dir 
> innodb_disable_sort_file_cache    OFF innodb_doublewrite  ON
> innodb_fast_shutdown  1 innodb_file_format    Antelope
> innodb_file_format_check  ON innodb_file_format_max   Antelope
> innodb_file_per_table ON innodb_flush_log_at_timeout  1
> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit    1 innodb_flush_method   
> innodb_flush_neighbors    1 innodb_flushing_avg_loops 30
> innodb_force_load_corrupted   OFF innodb_force_recovery   0
> innodb_ft_aux_table    innodb_ft_cache_size   8000000
> innodb_ft_enable_diag_print   OFF innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
> innodb_ft_max_token_size  84 innodb_ft_min_token_size 3
> innodb_ft_num_word_optimize   2000
> innodb_ft_result_cache_limit  2000000000
> innodb_ft_server_stopword_table    innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree  2
> innodb_ft_total_cache_size    640000000 innodb_ft_user_stopword_table 
> innodb_io_capacity    200 innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
> innodb_large_prefix   OFF innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
> innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog    OFF innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216
> innodb_log_compressed_pages   ON innodb_log_file_size 50331648
> innodb_log_files_in_group 2 innodb_log_group_home_dir .\
> innodb_lru_scan_depth 1024 innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct 75
> innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm    0 innodb_max_purge_lag  0
> innodb_max_purge_lag_delay    0 innodb_mirrored_log_groups    1
> innodb_monitor_disable     innodb_monitor_enable   innodb_monitor_reset   
> innodb_monitor_reset_all   innodb_old_blocks_pct  37
> innodb_old_blocks_time    1000 innodb_online_alter_log_max_size   134217728
> innodb_open_files 300 innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
> innodb_page_size  16384 innodb_print_all_deadlocks    OFF
> innodb_purge_batch_size   300 innodb_purge_threads    1
> innodb_random_read_ahead  OFF innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
> innodb_read_io_threads    4 innodb_read_only  OFF
> innodb_replication_delay  0 innodb_rollback_on_timeout    OFF
> innodb_rollback_segments  128 innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
> innodb_spin_wait_delay    6 innodb_stats_auto_recalc  ON
> innodb_stats_method   nulls_equal innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
> innodb_stats_persistent   ON innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages 20
> innodb_stats_sample_pages 8 innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages   8
> innodb_status_output  OFF innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
> innodb_strict_mode    OFF innodb_support_xa   ON innodb_sync_array_size   1
> innodb_sync_spin_loops    30 innodb_table_locks   ON
> innodb_thread_concurrency 17 innodb_thread_sleep_delay    1250
> innodb_undo_directory . innodb_undo_logs  128 innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
> innodb_use_native_aio ON innodb_use_sys_malloc    ON
> innodb_version    5.6.23 innodb_write_io_threads  4
> interactive_timeout   28800 join_buffer_size  262144
> keep_files_on_create  OFF key_buffer_size 8388608
> key_cache_age_threshold   300 key_cache_block_size    1024
> key_cache_division_limit  100 large_files_support ON large_page_size  0
> large_pages   OFF lc_messages en_US lc_messages_dir   C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\ lc_time_names en_US license   GPL
> local_infile  ON lock_wait_timeout    31536000 log_bin    OFF
> log_bin_basename   log_bin_index   log_bin_trust_function_creators    OFF
> log_bin_use_v1_row_events OFF log_error   .\CL-T226-164CN.err
> log_output    FILE log_queries_not_using_indexes  OFF
> log_slave_updates OFF log_slow_admin_statements   OFF
> log_slow_slave_statements OFF log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
> log_warnings  1 long_query_time   10 low_priority_updates OFF
> lower_case_file_system    ON lower_case_table_names   1
> master_info_repository    FILE master_verify_checksum OFF
> max_allowed_packet    4194304 max_binlog_cache_size   1.84467E+19
> max_binlog_size   1073741824 max_binlog_stmt_cache_size   1.84467E+19
> max_connect_errors    100 max_connections 151 max_delayed_threads 20
> max_error_count   64 max_heap_table_size  16777216
> max_insert_delayed_threads    20 max_join_size    1.84467E+19
> max_length_for_sort_data  1024 max_prepared_stmt_count    16382
> max_relay_log_size    0 max_seeks_for_key 4294967295 max_sort_length  1024
> max_sp_recursion_depth    0 max_tmp_tables    32 max_user_connections 0
> max_write_lock_count  4294967295 metadata_locks_cache_size    1024
> metadata_locks_hash_instances 8 min_examined_row_limit    0
> multi_range_count 256 myisam_data_pointer_size    6
> myisam_max_sort_file_size 1.07374E+11 myisam_mmap_size    1.84467E+19
> myisam_recover_options    OFF myisam_repair_threads   1
> myisam_sort_buffer_size   3221225472 myisam_stats_method  nulls_unequal
> myisam_use_mmap   OFF named_pipe  ON net_buffer_length    16384
> net_read_timeout  30 net_retry_count  10 net_write_timeout    60 new  OFF
> old   OFF old_alter_table OFF old_passwords   0 open_files_limit  6209
> optimizer_prune_level 1 optimizer_search_depth    62
> optimizer_switch  index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on
> optimizer_trace   enabled=off,one_line=off
> optimizer_trace_features  greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
> optimizer_trace_limit 1 optimizer_trace_max_mem_size  16384
> optimizer_trace_offset    -1 performance_schema   ON
> performance_schema_accounts_size  100
> performance_schema_digests_size   10000
> performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size    10000
> performance_schema_events_stages_history_size 10
> performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size    10000
> performance_schema_events_statements_history_size 10
> performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size 10000
> performance_schema_events_waits_history_size  10
> performance_schema_hosts_size 100
> performance_schema_max_cond_classes   80
> performance_schema_max_cond_instances 3504
> performance_schema_max_file_classes   50
> performance_schema_max_file_handles   32768
> performance_schema_max_file_instances 6770
> performance_schema_max_mutex_classes  200
> performance_schema_max_mutex_instances    15906
> performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes 40
> performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances   9102
> performance_schema_max_socket_classes 10
> performance_schema_max_socket_instances   322
> performance_schema_max_stage_classes  150
> performance_schema_max_statement_classes  168
> performance_schema_max_table_handles  4000
> performance_schema_max_table_instances    12500
> performance_schema_max_thread_classes 50
> performance_schema_max_thread_instances   402
> performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size 512
> performance_schema_setup_actors_size  100
> performance_schema_setup_objects_size 100
> performance_schema_users_size 100 pid_file    C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL
> Server 5.6\Data\cl-t226-164cn.pid plugin_dir  C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\plugin\ port 3306
> preload_buffer_size   32768 profiling OFF profiling_history_size  15
> protocol_version  10 query_alloc_block_size   8192
> query_cache_limit 1048576 query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
> query_cache_size  0 query_cache_type  OFF
> query_cache_wlock_invalidate  OFF query_prealloc_size 8192
> range_alloc_block_size    4096 read_buffer_size   65536 read_only OFF
> read_rnd_buffer_size  262144 relay_log     relay_log_basename 
> relay_log_index    relay_log_info_file    relay-log.info
> relay_log_info_repository FILE relay_log_purge    ON
> relay_log_recovery    OFF relay_log_space_limit   0 report_host   
> report_password    report_port    3306 report_user    
> rpl_stop_slave_timeout    31536000 secure_auth    ON secure_file_priv 
> server_id 1 server_id_bits    32
> server_uuid   5cd06577-b404-11e4-9e0d-002590c937e3 shared_memory  ON
> shared_memory_base_name   MYSQL simplified_binlog_gtid_recovery   OFF
> skip_external_locking ON skip_name_resolve    OFF skip_networking OFF
> skip_show_database    OFF slave_allow_batching    OFF
> slave_checkpoint_group    512 slave_checkpoint_period 300
> slave_compressed_protocol OFF slave_exec_mode STRICT
> slave_load_tmpdir C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp
> slave_max_allowed_packet  1073741824 slave_net_timeout    3600
> slave_parallel_workers    0 slave_pending_jobs_size_max   16777216
> slave_rows_search_algorithms  TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
> slave_skip_errors OFF slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
> slave_transaction_retries 10 slave_type_conversions   
> slow_launch_time  2 slow_query_log    ON
> slow_query_log_file   CL-T226-164CN-slow.log socket   MYSQL
> sort_buffer_size  262144 sql_auto_is_null OFF sql_big_selects ON
> sql_buffer_result OFF sql_log_bin ON sql_log_off  OFF
> sql_mode  STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
> sql_notes ON sql_quote_show_create    ON sql_safe_updates OFF
> sql_select_limit  1.84467E+19 sql_slave_skip_counter  0 sql_warnings  OFF
> ssl_ca     ssl_capath  ssl_cert    ssl_cipher  ssl_crl     ssl_crlpath    
> ssl_key    storage_engine InnoDB stored_program_cache 256 sync_binlog 0
> sync_frm  ON sync_master_info 10000 sync_relay_log    10000
> sync_relay_log_info   10000 system_time_zone  
> table_definition_cache    1400 table_open_cache   2000
> table_open_cache_instances    1 thread_cache_size 10
> thread_concurrency    10 thread_handling  one-thread-per-connection
> thread_stack  262144 time_format  %H:%i:%s time_zone  SYSTEM
> timed_mutexes OFF tmp_table_size  2147483648
> tmpdir    C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp
> transaction_alloc_block_size  8192 transaction_prealloc_size  4096
> tx_isolation  REPEATABLE-READ tx_read_only    OFF unique_checks   ON
> updatable_views_with_limit    YES version 5.6.23-log
> version_comment   MySQL Community Server (GPL)
> version_compile_machine   x86_64 version_compile_os   Win64
> wait_timeout  28800
```

**Status**

```
Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 0
Aborted_connects    0
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  10979
Bytes_sent  44674
Com_admin_commands  260
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   1
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_create_db   2
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    3
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  0
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 2
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  0
Com_insert_select   0
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  12
Com_set_option  18
Com_signal  0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 0
Com_show_function_code  0
Com_show_function_status    1
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_code 0
Com_show_procedure_status   1
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 4
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 1
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  4
Com_show_warnings   1
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  0
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 3
Created_tmp_disk_tables 2
Created_tmp_files   8
Created_tmp_tables  11
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  3
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   172
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  8
Handler_read_key    5
Handler_read_last   0
Handler_read_next   0
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   909
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   781
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   10572
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   173211648
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    8305
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   644786
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   2
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  655360
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   128
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    872915
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    6116
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   432215
Innodb_data_fsyncs  10966
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    102371328
Innodb_data_reads   6859
Innodb_data_writes  17201
Innodb_data_written 292975616
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  8305
Innodb_dblwr_writes 1506
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   43467
Innodb_log_writes   4033
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    4090
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   20808192
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    4329
Innodb_pages_read   6243
Innodb_pages_written    8305
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    0
Innodb_row_lock_waits   0
Innodb_rows_deleted 0
Innodb_rows_inserted    0
Innodb_rows_read    0
Innodb_rows_updated 0
Innodb_num_open_files   300
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   6698
Key_blocks_used 0
Key_read_requests   0
Key_reads   0
Key_write_requests  0
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 0
Last_query_partial_plans    0
Max_used_connections    2
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  19
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  71
Open_tables 64
Opened_files    748
Opened_table_definitions    74
Opened_tables   71
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  0
Qcache_free_memory  0
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   0
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 0
Queries 312
Questions   51
Select_full_join    2
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    0
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 17
Slave_heartbeat_period  0
Slave_last_heartbeat    
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    2
Sort_merge_passes   0
Sort_range  0
Sort_rows   0
Sort_scan   0
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_server_not_after    
Ssl_server_not_before   
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   86
Table_locks_waited  0
Table_open_cache_hits   15
Table_open_cache_misses 71
Table_open_cache_overflows  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  0
Threads_connected   2
Threads_created 2
Threads_running 1
Uptime  73600
Uptime_since_flush_status   73600
```

Answer (score 0):

> 615MB Ram

That is very tiny.  (The other machines are more civilized.)

You have not said what version you are running, nor which ENGINE that table uses.

That CREATE TABLE needs to create 300 "tables" to implement the partitioning.  This takes time, depending on the OS (Windows is slow) and on various settings.  I could go into details after knowing versions and engine.

You are likely to be thrashing on some internal table because of trying to have 300 to 900 files open at once.  And it is likely that the settings are different on the different machines.  THAT may be the cause of the different timings!

But what I really want to do is convince you not to use PARTITION BY HASH.  It does nothing for performance.  Remove the PARTITIONing, and rethink the indexes -- they probably need rearranging to accommodate not having "partition pruning".

If you goal is just to benchmark CREATE TABLE, then I ask "why".  That is, or at least should be, an extremely rare task in any production database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here are more details: 

615 MB is not used for anything I just tested on an Amazon VM instance to give idea of time taken for comparison.

I am using 5.6 version and Innodb engine

I agree that 300 tables creation takes time but there is some abnormal time taken on server compared to other two environments. You may be right about thrashing or some other issue that we are trying to figure out.

Comment: My basic reason for partitioning by community id is that my data is already separate for separate communities they do not interact with each other. Also that helps me avoid deadlocks when edit is performed on one community it will not block edits of other community for OS page as they are all separate files. I am just a beginner and this is my thought process. You may be right that I may be able to solve the provlem just by right indexing, will it also help me avoid edit deadlocks ?

I am not benchmarking create table :)

Comment: Can RAID be an issue ? I have two mirror disks on my server is it possible that MySQL is not optimized or OS is doing something because of RAID or mirror disks. I read something that journaling can take time

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56062/slow-innodb-insert-update-delete

Comment: Having a good index, preferably UNIQUE or PRIMARY, is key to minimizing deadlocks.

Comment: Mirrored disks _should_ be irrelevant.

Comment: What could be the reason then ? I am troubleshooting this for last four days ! Anything that I can try ?

Comment: There are several settings that _may_ be causing trouble.  If you would like to post SHOW VARIABLES and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS for the 32GB system, I may be able to spot something.

Comment: I have added Variables and Status to my original post. Thanks !