# Suitability of mysql on a raid 5 server with raid card

Tags: mysql, raid

I would like to ask is mysql ok to run a on a raid 5 server. The raid is done using  hardware raid and not software. I saw some older links like this [Is raid 5 suitable for a mysql installation?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12977/is-raid-5-suitable-for-a-mysql-installation) which gives negative opinion on settings raid 5? As time pass I guess hardware have improve and I guess it should be better now ? Any opinion ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're comparing, RAID-10 is still a better architecture than RAID-5. My opinion is that regardless of hardware improvement the underlying functionality still remains the same for RAID-5.

(Even though Ronado's answer has "If you do not use innodb_file_per_table...", he'd still recommend the same.)

Comment: The problem is that customer is affording only 3 hd so the best is to go with raid 5 or is there any other option to go with ? Yes I will be using innodb_file_per_table

Comment: So with 3 harddisk what is best solution then ?

Comment: Use RAID-5 with 3 drives.